# What's the most efficient way to remove all symbols from an object?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an object where I want to keep internal-only key/pairs with symbols.  Given...

```
let obj = {
    [Symbol.for('foo')]: 'internal-only member',
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
```

When I return these to a client through my API, I want to strip out all Symbols from the Object because the client doesn't have any use for them.

I'd like a generic function that will return:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
```

In other words:

```
returnScrubbedObj = (obj) => {
    // filter/map/remove/copy etc the original object to a new object without symbols 
    return objWithoutSymbols
}
```

I know there are probably many different ways to do this; just looking for the best/most efficient one.

Comment: try ```JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))```

Comment: Normally I would think `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` would work but maybe because I'm using TypeScript (didn't mention that above) it is changing the definition of the object as this doesn't remove the symbols from the object.  Strange.

Comment: I think that I was doing something wrong as this does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JSON methods:

```js
let obj = {[Symbol.for('foo')]:'internal-only member',a:1,b:2,c:3};
const res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(res);
```

A more verbose version using `reduce` and `typeof`:

```js
let obj = {[Symbol.for('foo')]:'internal-only member',a:1,b:2,c:3};
const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => typeof k == "symbol" ? acc : (acc[k] = v, acc), {});
console.log(res);
```

And since you asked about the efficiency, [the `reduce` method is faster](https://jsbench.me/9rjw614ulc/1).

Comment: Seems like there is no need in `typeof === "symbol` checking: `Object.entries` already exclude symbols from resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries and build a new object of the entries.

```js
let obj = {
    [Symbol.for('foo')]: 'internal-only member',
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer except that I'm not on ECMA2019 yet.  I'll bookmark this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient and less memory and space intensive to use `for .. in` here on the object.

```js
let obj = {
    [Symbol.for('foo')]: 'internal-only member',
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}

let newObj = {};
for(let prop in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
     newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
  }
}

console.log(newObj);
```